# Invalid input Error following Forecasting E-Book in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I am following the [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](http://otexts.org/fpp2/index.html) book which is great. But even though I copy the codes sometimes my code gives error and does not work. I have the fpp2, ggplot2 libraries.

```
beer2 <- window(ausbeer, start=1992)
fit.beer <- tslm(beer2 ~ trend + season)

  autoplot(beer2, series="Data") +
  forecast::autolayer(fitted(fit.beer), series="Fitted") +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Megalitres") +
  ggtitle("Quarterly Beer Production")
```

Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

How can I resolve this error? The code can be found in http://otexts.org/fpp2/Regr-UsefulPredictors.html

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1](http://otexts.org/fpp2/index.html) LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1](http://otexts.org/fpp2/index.html) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1](http://otexts.org/fpp2/index.html) scales_0.5.0    GGally_1.3.2    bindrcpp_0.2    readxl_1.0.0    quantmod_0.4-11 TTR_0.23-2      CADFtest_0.3-3 
 [8] urca_1.3-0      sandwich_2.4-0  dynlm_0.3-5     Quandl_2.8.0    tseries_0.10-42 ggfortify_0.4.1 fpp2_2.1
[15] ggplot2_2.2.1   expsmooth_2.3   fma_2.3         forecast_8.2    xts_0.10-0      zoo_1.8-0       xlsx_0.5.7
[22] xlsxjars_0.6.1  rJava_0.9-9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1](http://otexts.org/fpp2/index.html) Rcpp_0.12.13       lattice_0.20-35    tidyr_0.7.2        prettyunits_1.0.2  digest_0.6.12      assertthat_0.2.0
 [7] lmtest_0.9-35      R6_2.2.2           cellranger_1.1.0   plyr_1.8.4         MatrixModels_0.4-1 httr_1.3.1
[13] progress_1.1.2     rlang_0.1.2        lazyeval_0.2.1     curl_3.0           minqa_1.2.4        SparseM_1.77
[19] car_2.1-5          fracdiff_1.4-2     nloptr_1.0.4       Matrix_1.2-11      labeling_0.3       splines_3.4.2
[25] lme4_1.1-14        stringr_1.2.0      munsell_0.4.3      compiler_3.4.2     pkgconfig_2.0.1    mgcv_1.8-20
[31] nnet_7.3-12        tidyselect_0.2.3   tibble_1.3.4       gridExtra_2.3      quadprog_1.5-5     reshape_0.8.7
[37] dplyr_0.7.4        MASS_7.3-47        grid_3.4.2         nlme_3.1-131       jsonlite_1.5       gtable_0.2.0
[43] magrittr_1.5       stringi_1.1.5      reshape2_1.4.2     timeDate_3012.100  RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tools_3.4.2
[49] glue_1.2.0         purrr_0.2.4        parallel_3.4.2     pbkrtest_0.4-7     colorspace_1.3-2   bindr_0.1
[55] quantreg_5.34

Comment: I just tried it works for me. can you restart your R studio and load only those two packages and try?

Comment: Yes It works for me now! Why would that happen is it because of the interaction of different packages?

Comment: ggfortify does not play nicely with the forecast package.